# iOS Simulator Not Responding Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, ios16, xcode14

Lately, after 2/3 launches of a project (sometimes after first launch), the simulator stops responding and have I to close/kill it and launch it again to fix the issue.

Is anyone else having a similar issue? Any solutions??

I'm unsure if this is due to Xcode not killing the old instance properly, or the Simulator itself. Having to do this multiple times a day adds up and it is becoming very incovenient!

**Environment**:
MacOS Ventura
Xcode 14.1
iPhone 14 Pro Sim iOS 16.1

So far I've tried updating Xcode, restarting the computer, removing derived data. Still no fix.